# Android share to facebook twitter g+ and others

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, share

New to android here but not to stackoverflow, i know this was asked before but hear me out first:
So regular Share through chooser:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
```

**No longer works!**, facebook doesn't allow pre-filled text to be sent(so i understood).

**BUT** I've seen apps do it anyways, by first presenting a pre-filled dialog they created with the text and then showing a custom chooser for sharing.

I have no idea how they do that, i can't find any answers in the forums for pre-filled text share to facebook.

Worst part is, i want to share text with an image, like in this photo [here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Simple-Social-Sharing/raw/master/FacebookPost.png).

Where can i get a good sample project / Tutorial for:
1. simple facebook share.

2. twitter and google+ sharing.
3. custom chooser.

Also, would like to hear your comments and regards on best practices with social media sharing AND using a chooser.
Cause i also want the be able to share to apps like WhatsApp and other of that sorts.

Comment: facebook never allowed prefilling the message. read about it in the platform policy (which you would have to read anyway if you want to create a facebook app): https://developers.facebook.com/policy

Comment: K, so how can i transfer text to the message?

Comment: by presenting a dialog where the user can enter the text

Comment: No. There is a different solution.
I saw an app that shows the text in the app itself and then shares it on behalf of the user through facebook app. :/
So it is possible...
Also i now know that that for working chooser i must create a custom one to get facebook to work cause facebook demands the usage of their sdk.

Comment: you can use the graph api with publish_actions to post something, but it has to get approved by facebook now and you are not allowed to prefill the message. it always has to be 100% user generated.

Comment: apps prefilling the message will stop working after april 2015, they are using an old v1.0 app. but even then it was not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

With facebook's new SDK you can no longer use ACTION_SEND to share text information.
You can post on behalf of the user but not pre-fill the text for a status update, at least i did not find a way to do that.

You must also have your app actions checked and accepted by facebooks policy.

The answer: Stop working with facebook untill they remove their app from the ACTION_SEND in the android chooser.

Comment: that´s not correct and not at all what i commented. you CAN post on behalf of the user.